# Does android studio 2 support Java 8 and Lambda expression?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

The official version 2 of Android Studio has been released 2 days ago.

Does this version support Java 8 ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for how to enable lambda notation support for java 8 on Android Studio 2.1

First you need to set JDK location to java 8 in under project structure -> SDK Location

Right now Android Studio 2.1 does not support lambda notation for java 8 but there is workaround for that.

You need to enable Jack compiler to support this feature
Add android { jackOptions { enabled true } } in build.gradle file
Also it would require Android Sdk Build-tools 24 or later. To download that open standalone SDK manager under sdk manager and download

Comment: Hi Prashant!  I'm using AndroidStudio 2.2.2  My `"SDK Location"` (this is on a Mac FWIW) just says `"/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk"`  Am I using Java8 - how to use Java8??  Thanks!

Comment: you should check your `jdk location`, you are looking at your `android sdk`.